# Pointer to element of array pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am working on a project, where i have problem with understanding the logic. I would appreciate i someone could explain it to me or make it at least more clear.
Data structure is hash table if it changes something.

**Code:**

```
typedef struct tHTElem {
    char* key;
    int data;
    struct tHTElem* ptrnext;
} tHTElem;  

typedef tHTElem* tHT[MAX_SIZE];
```

As long as i understand this, `tHT[]` is array of pointers to structure `tHTElem` ?
So if i want to create pointer to one element of this array, i should create it like this ?

```
tHTElem *ptrToElem = NULL;
```

And initialize it like this ?

```
ptrToElem = tHT[42];
```

I am kinda lost in this..
Thank you for any advice.

Comment: You need to provide context, it's not clear what or why you need `ptrToElem`. Also, `tHTElem *ptrToElem = NULL`, already initialized `ptrToElem` to `NULL`.

Comment: why `MAX_SIZE`? `tHT` is a type name, so you cannot index it.

Comment: I ment to initialize it to exact element of that has table.. i am just confused how to use reference and dereference in exat this situation
And why MAX_SIZE ? it is just a max length of "list of possible keys"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the `typedef` in the line
`typedef tHTElem* tHT[MAX_SIZE];`
Because when you declared the struct you already used the `typedef` statement. Since then, you only need to use the type name, which is `tHTElem`.

No matter the type, when you declare an array, you are declaring a pointer. So this: `char **c` is equal to this: `char * c[]`, it means `c` is a pointer to somewhere in the memory where there is a pointer to an array.

In your case you have a `tHTElem* tHT[MAX_SIZE];`, which is the same as `tHTElem** tHT;`. So if you want to create a poiter to the element 42 you should do like this:

```
tHTElem *ptrToElem;
ptrToElem = *tHT[42];
```

The `*` in the `... = *tHT[42];` is for you to access the memory where the array is and the 42 is the position of it.